# React/Javascript: Chaining together filters together

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, reactjs, algorithm

I have this function that takes a array of texts for a few filters and filters out related data but I need to figure out a way to chain these together for example. IF 2 of these filters are selected like shown in the picture it should meet both of the requirements not one or the other.
[image]
This last value should be filtered out since it doesn't include FIN and PSFC

```js
const value = {
  Value: [{
      "Activity Id": "04912309-35",
      "Activity Name": "SCAFFOLD SUPPORT TEAM - CARPENTERS & LABORERS",
      "Start Date ": "2021-06-29 08:45:21",
      "End Date": "2021-06-30 08:45:21",
      "Work Group Name": "PSCF",
      "Unit ": "01",
      Status: "READY",
      crew: "FIN",
      "Work Pln Factor": "F2 EN RS NR",
    },
    {
      "Activity Id": "RHR*SWPUMPDSCHSTOP*Z",
      "Activity Name": "MM 1E12-F332D CLEAN UP AFTER  DISASSEMBLE/INSPECT/REPAIR VALVE",
      "Start Date ": "2021-06-29 08:45:21",
      "End Date": "2021-07-09 08:45:21",
      "Work Group Name": "PME1",
      "Unit ": "02",
      Status: "WORKING",
      crew: "FIN",
      "Work Pln Factor": "F1 RM L2 NR",
    },
    {
      "Activity Id": "01322927-01B",
      "Activity Name": "2DG024 WALK C/O, DISASSEMBLE VALVE",
      "Start Date ": "2021-06-29 08:45:21",
      "End Date": "2021-06-29 16:45:21",
      "Work Group Name": "ES MM",
      "Unit ": "02",
      Status: "H/APPR",
      crew: "FIN",
      "Work Pln Factor": "F2 WE RS NR L1 HS",
    },
    {
      "Activity Id": "01881463-01Z",
      "Activity Name": "MM 2CP40MD CLEAN UP AFTER REPLACE FILTER ELEMENT",
      "Start Date ": "2021-06-29 08:45:21",
      "End Date": "2021-06-29 20:45:21",
      "Work Group Name": "PME1",
      "Unit ": "01",
      Status: "PLAN",
      crew: "",
      "Work Pln Factor": "F2 EN RS NR",
    },
    {
      "Activity Id": "DG*VLV*BRIDGES*BN",
      "Activity Name": "MM 2E22-S001 FILL ENGINE OIL",
      "Start Date ": "2021-06-29 08:45:21",
      "End Date": "2021-06-29 14:45:21",
      "Work Group Name": "MM",
      "Unit ": "01",
      Status: "",
      crew: "",
      "Work Pln Factor": "RM",
    },
    {
      "Activity Id": "04912309-3434",
      "Activity Name": "MM 2E22-S001 FILL ENGINE OIL zzzz",
      "Start Date ": "2021-06-29 08:45:21",
      "End Date": "2021-06-29 08:45:21",
      "Work Group Name": "PSCF",
      "Unit ": "01",
      Status: "",
      crew: "",
      "Work Pln Factor": "F2 WE RS NR L1 H",
    },
  ];
}
```

This dispatches filtered data

```
 const handleFilterStructor = (str: string, state: any) => {
 let value;
 state === 'Select All'
  ? (value = data)
  : (value = data.filter((each: any) => each[str].includes(state)));

 dispatch(updateScheduleData({ Value: value }));
 };
```

This is the react hook that listen for state changes

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
workGroup && handleFilterStructor('Work Group Name', workGroup);
crew && handleFilterStructor('crew', crew);
risk && handleFilterStructor('Work Pln Factor', risk);
// eslint-disable-next-line
}, [workGroup, crew, risk]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: I had to also handle for selectAll since the one below didn't

```
   const handleFilterStructor = (work: any, crew: any, risk: any) => {
    let value;
    let SA = 'Select All';
    value = data.filter(
      (each: any) =>
        ((work !== SA && each['Work Group Name'].includes(work)) ||
          work === SA) &&
        ((crew !== SA && each['crew'].includes(crew)) || crew === SA) &&
        ((risk !== SA && each['Work Pln Factor'].includes(risk)) || risk === SA)
    );
    dispatch(updateScheduleData({ Value: value }));
  };
```

I had to chain together to functions like this

```
 const handleFilterStructor = (work: string, crew: string, risk: string) => {
    let value;
    work === 'Select All' || crew === 'Select All' || risk === 'Select All'
      ? (value = data)
      : (value = data.filter(
          (each: any) =>
            each['Work Group Name'].includes(work) &&
            each['crew'].includes(crew) &&
            each['Work Pln Factor'].includes(risk)
        ));
    dispatch(updateScheduleData({ Value: value }));
  };
```

Than combine the 3 check into one so the use effect

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    (workGroup || crew || risk) && handleFilterStructor(workGroup, crew, risk);
  }, [workGroup, crew, risk]);
```

Comment: Would like some idea on simplifing this even further